# Proyecto en git para macOS y Windows

Tags: windows, git, github, macos

Tengo una estación de trabajo en casa bajo macOS, y luego un portátil bajo Windows.
He comenzado a trabajar con git para ser mas productivo, pero el problema ha sido cuando después de crear un proyecto web en el imac con `npm` utilizando bootstrap, font-awesome como dependencias y gulp, gulp-sass, browser-sync, etc como dependencias de desarrollo, al hacer un pull bajo Windows, me da errores de dependencia al sistema operativo.

He probado lo mismo pero al revés, he creado el proyecto bajo win, pero al intentar trabajar bajo macOS, me tira de dependencias del sistema.

¿Hay alguna forma de trabajar con un repositorio independientemente del sistema operativo?

Este es el repositorio, donde estoy trabajando.

https://github.com/kherop/the-band

> Windows PowerShell
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.
>   PS C:\Users\Portatil-Luis\Desktop\git\the-band> gulp serve
>   C:\Users\Portatil-Luis\Desktop\git\the-band\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15
>         throw new Error(errors.missingBinary());
>         ^
>   Error: Missing binding C:\Users\Portatil-Luis\Desktop\git\the-band\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node
>   Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 8.x
>   Found bindings for the following environments:
>     - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 8.x
>   This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
>   Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.
>       at module.exports (C:\Users\Portatil-Luis\Desktop\git\the-band\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:13)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Portatil-Luis\Desktop\git\the-band\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Portatil-Luis\Desktop\git\the-band\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:187:21)
>   PS C:\Users\Portatil-Luis\Desktop\git\the-band>

acabo de darme cuenta que poniendo lo que me dicen:
npm rebuild node-sass --force
me crea nuevo archivos y lo puedo ejecutar mi "gulp serve" sin problemas.
Pero me crea nuevo archivos que estan pendientes de subirse en el proximo commit.

Perdonar mi incultura al respecto, soy diseñador grafico, y esto se me escapa.

Cuando yo diseño una interface y la mando a cualquier sitio, esta se ve y se abre bajo el mismo software psd, ai, sketch, etc.. seguramente este equivocado, pero no entiendo porque no puedo ver el proyecto y trabajar con el en diferentes sistemas operativos, y mas cuando he creado un .json con dependecias de produccion y desarrollo.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu problema, pero puedes utilizar docker para que no dependas de los entornos de desarollo

Comment: he añadido el problema que me da, lo que me pasa es que no puedo trabajar con el mismo repositorio desde window o desde el mac, me da problemas

Comment: Ya intentaste correr `npm rebuild node-sass --force`?

Comment: justo eso te decia, no lo entiendo

Comment: Añadiste la carpeta node_modules al archivo `.gitignore`?

Comment: Acabo de ver tu repo, y definitivamente te hace falta un `.gitignore`

Comment: creo que no, como puedo hacer eso, gracias :))

Comment: Me imagino que cuando dices ios quieres decir macOS?

Comment: correcto, pero no es la primera vez que me pasa, hace poco trabaje con una empresa desarrollando la interface de una web app con angular y tambien me dio problemas, no creia que era tan importante esto

Answer (score 2):

**Solución rápida**

Ejecuta el comando `npm rebuild node-sass --force` como te lo describen en el error en la consola.

**Solución efectiva**

El problema viene derivado de no tener un archivo `.gitignore` por lo tanto los archivos de la carpeta *node_modules* están siendo cargados a tu repositorio remoto cada vez que haces push, esto no es deseado ya que los paquetes a veces dependen de un sistema operativo, de los programas instalados en tu entorno de desarollo, entre otras cosas.

Primero tienes que crear un archivo `.gitignore` en la raíz de tu proyecto, lo ideal es incluirlo apenas empiezas el proyecto (GitHub tiene un [listado](https://github.com/github/gitignore) de archivos para que utilices el que mejor se adapte a tu proyecto, te recomiendo utilizar el de node) e introducir esta linea:

```
node_modules/
```

Luego vamos a quitar la carpeta de *node_modules* ejecutando los siguientes comandos

```
git rm -r --cached node_modules
git commit -m "Remove node_modules"
```

No te olvides agregar tu archivo nuevo

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Add gitignore"
```

Y por último subimos los cambios al repositorio

```
git push origin master
```